# get the category of an android app - at server side

Tags: php

I have this case where in our in-house app is capturing all the applications used by the user, and uploads the list to our cloud server, where I need to categorize them by the "category" at play store.

It would have been better if the android code could also find the category of an application by its package name, but looks like my developers were having problem doing this at the android end.

How do we find out the category of an application by using just its package name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets just pick one of the package name say "com.facebook.katana", and lets google it.

the first result (if its a valid android app) would be the play url like - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana, lets hit this url and look at the source of it.

a span like this has what we need -

```
<span itemprop="genre">Social</span>
```

Now lets write a dirty index game in php to get the genre or category of our package, i hope y'all find it easy to understand, coz it ain't rocket science

the code is available here https://gist.github.com/brijrajsingh/6915711
and is given below as well.

Note - I would also suggest that once you have got a category for a package name you better store it in some db or memcache, so you don't need to hit it again and again for diff packages, also the code might stop running if you bombard the google servers, so go easy on it.

```
<?php

class PackageCategory
{

  protected static $playurl = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=';

  public function PackageCategory($packageName) {
        $this->packageName = $packageName;
    }

    public function getPackageCategory()
    {       
        $result = $this->makeRequest(self::$playurl.$this->packageName);        
        //starting index of category tag
        $indexstart = strpos($result,"<span itemprop=\"genre\">");

        //ending index of category tag
        $indexend = strpos($result,"</span>",$indexstart);

        $category = substr($result,$indexstart+23,$indexend - ($indexstart+23));
        echo $category;
    }

//curl to the play store
 /**
     * Makes request to AWIS
     * @param String $url   URL to make request to
     * @return String       Result of request
     */
    protected function makeRequest($url) {
        //echo "\nMaking request to:\n$url\n";
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

}


    if (count($argv) < 2) {
    echo "Usage: $argv[0] PackageName\n";
    exit(-1);
}
else {
    $packageName = $argv[1];   
}

$packageCategory = new PackageCategory($packageName);
$packageCategory->getPackageCategory();

 ?>
```

Comment: Take note that the category name is depended to the language the Play store is shown. When I use English, I get "Social". However, when I use Japanese, it will be "ソーシャルネットワーク". However, I also just found out `<a class="document-subtitle category" href="/store/apps/category/SOCIAL">` in the source code, which doesn't depend on the language since it's a part of the URL. Perhaps it can be better to use it instead.

Comment: It Works Great , But I want to know that is it safe to use? secondly will google block the IP of the site from where i am sending this link ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there seems to be a way:

Since you already found the  names of the application packages.

You can use [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) unofficial googleplay api to get the info you need about the app.